# How to get a list of imports in macro mode in haxe?

Tags: macros, haxe

How do you get the list of imports a .hx file uses in macro mode? More specificity, suppose I have a "haxe.macro.Position" that tells me which file an expression belongs to. I need to know the imports the file uses in order to convert abridged type declarations such as "Car" into full-package-path types such as "vehicles.fourWheels.Car".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is planned to add in haxe 3.3: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3560

At the moment, you may try to read the source file directly (as `String`) and parse the `import` statements manually.

For getting the fully-qualified type name, there is also [a suggestion made in the above mentioned issue](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3560#issuecomment-62765420):

```
var someComplexType:ComplexType = getComplexType();
switch (Context.typeof( macro ( _ : $someComplexType )))
{
    case TInst(_.get() => c,_):
      var pack = c.pack, name = c.name;
    case _: 
}
```

---

edit:

Here is a more complete solution to get the fully-qualified type name:

```
#if macro
import haxe.macro.*;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Type;
#end
import haxe.ds.Option;

class Test {
    #if macro
    static public function typeToTypePath(t:Type):TypePath {
        return switch (Context.follow(t)) {
            case TInst(t, params):
                baseTypeToTypePath(t.get(), [for (p in params) TPType(Context.toComplexType(p))]);
            case TEnum(t, params):
                baseTypeToTypePath(t.get(), [for (p in params) TPType(Context.toComplexType(p))]);
            case TType(t, params):
                baseTypeToTypePath(t.get(), [for (p in params) TPType(Context.toComplexType(p))]);
            case TAbstract(t, params):
                baseTypeToTypePath(t.get(), [for (p in params) TPType(Context.toComplexType(p))]);
            case _: throw 'Cannot convert this to TypePath: $t';
        };
    }

    static function baseTypeToTypePath(t:BaseType, params:Array<TypeParam>):TypePath {
        return {
            pack:t.pack, 
            name:t.module.substring(t.module.lastIndexOf(".")+1), 
            sub:t.name,
            params:params
        };
    }

    /**
        Fully-qualify a `ComplexType`.
        For example, turn `Option<Int>` to `haxe.ds.Option.Option<StdTypes.Int>`.
        In case the process fail, it will return the input `ComplexType`.
    */
    static public function qualifyComplexType(ct:ComplexType):ComplexType {
        var type = Context.typeof(macro ( null : $ct ));
        try {
            var tp = typeToTypePath(type);
            return TPath(tp);
        } catch(e:Dynamic) {
            return ct;
        }
    }
    #end

    /**
        Just an example to demostrate `qualifyComplexType`.
        It accepts an `e` expression in the form of `var _:Type`,
        and trace the fully-qualified name of `Type` at compile-time.
    */
    macro static public function printType(e:Expr):Expr {
        switch (e) {
            case macro var a:$ct:
                trace(ComplexTypeTools.toString(qualifyComplexType(ct)));
            case _:
        }
        return e;
    }


    static function main() {
        printType(var a:Int);          //StdTypes.Int
        printType(var a:Test);         //Test.Test
        printType(var a:Option<Int>);  //haxe.ds.Option.Option<StdTypes.Int>
        printType(var a:Void->Void);   //Void -> Void
    }
}
```

Comment: For the suggestion the "pack" won't usually have the module's path. Is this a problem? I don't fully understand the syntax you have there...

Comment: `_.get() => c` is using [extractor](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-extractors.html), and `c` is a [capture variable](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-variable-capture.html). `macro ( _ : $someComplexType )` is using [expression reification](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-expression.html), where the expression is a ["type check" expression](http://haxe.org/manual/expression-type-check.html). `c.pack` would be `haxe.ds` for `haxe.ds.Option`.

Anyway, I've updated the answer to include a more complete solution for you to play with ;)

Comment: Ok thanks. Wow haxe packs a punch with it's advanced capabilities despite not having many features! I still need to read up on all these things.